# iOS tap app icon enter app takes a long time to launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, launch

When I tap the icon of my app, it shows selected(means it darken). But still stay in home screen at that time. Many seconds later, it enter my app. Even a very simple app happens like this.

Comment: It happens on a simulator or on an actual device?

Comment: What have you done to analyze the launch sequence?  Have you checked logs?  Have you used Instruments?

Comment: Heavy operations in the AppDelegate method didFinishLaunching: tend to show this lag. Try and defer any functionality from that method.

Comment: @0ndre_ on the actual device

Comment: @Avi i have do nothing in my code sometime even in a blank project...

Comment: @ZeMoon i did nothing in didFinishLaunching: